# Does anyone have design a calendar with integrated appointment schedule in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want is that the user should be able to view the schedule date/week/month-wise. Once selected it should be inactive.

[image]

Comment: Do you want a design? Probably not a good question for SO/SE anyway but your better off at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ I belive.

Comment: No, I am looking for an example/sample flutter/dart code implementation of this.

Comment: You do not ask that in your question. I also think your question is too broad and unclear. Do you want your image but in code? Or is your image a part of the solution and you need the rest of it? I dont understand.

Comment: Sure next I will try to be clearer. Yes, I need the image in code too. I was thinking of using TabBar, but do not know how to correspond to the respective date displayed below in the ListView.